# HDMI sound working in Ubuntu 14.10 live USB, stops working after install

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

Configuration:

- AMD Kabini A4-5350
- TV hooked up to onboard HDMI

In the live disk version of Ubuntu 14.10 x64 HDMI sound output tests as working, and appears as the primary volume in the top right if I mute the other outputs.

After installation this is no longer the case.

All software seems to know about the card and show it running; `aplay`, `alsamixer`, `pavucontrol`, **Sound Settings**.  All software shows output unmuted.  No sound actually escapes except the speakers pop when power cycles.

Same problem more-or-less in 14.04.  I didn't try sound in the live USB there.

Answer (score 1):

Cycling power to the TV fixes the problem.  Cycling power on the computer with the TV on causes the problem.  I think this is just HDMI being its crappy self.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting the output device in the sound settings menu from default to HDMI? I had to do this while watching a movie! Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: And now it decides to work.  I'm beginning to think this is just HDCP being HDCP.  Sound works in the sound settings test now.  Except for the part where it's muted for the first half second if you haven't played a sound for a few seconds.  Also crackles a lot. A power management feature maybe?

Comment: tsched=0 in the pulse config seems to fix crackling but not startup latency.